# Unable to pip install aiohttp python

Tags: python, aiohttp

Actually I'm just trying to install discord via pip and after some initial trouble achieving this. However I still get a traceback error. 
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiohttp'"
I tried so much now, via pip there is again an error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.285]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

C:\Users\Laptop>pip install aiohttp
Collecting aiohttp
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7a/58/4476d96f35cc18a5133330f06c9ff3bc44fa64a9b6d15d2716efa6043b80/aiohttp-3.4.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4.0,>=2.0 in c:\users\laptop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp) (3.0.4)
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0 (from aiohttp)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/b8/057c3e5b546ff4b24263164ecda13f6962d85c9dc477fcc0bcdcb3adb658/yarl-1.2.6.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<5.0,>=4.0 in c:\users\laptop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in c:\users\laptop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp) (18.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0 in c:\users\laptop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp) (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in c:\users\laptop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp) (2.7)
Building wheels for collected packages: yarl
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for yarl ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\laptop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Laptop\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rak2eq35\\yarl\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-bz7m_99i --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\yarl
  copying yarl\quoting.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\yarl
  copying yarl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\yarl
  running egg_info
  writing yarl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to yarl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to yarl.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to yarl.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\_quoting.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\_quoting.*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\_quoting.pyd'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\_quoting.*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  writing manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying yarl\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win32-3.7\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting.c -> build\lib.win32-3.7\yarl
  copying yarl\_quoting.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.7\yarl
  copying yarl\py.typed -> build\lib.win32-3.7\yarl
  running build_ext
  building 'yarl._quoting' extension

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for yarl
  Running setup.py clean for yarl
Failed to build yarl
discord-py 0.16.12 has requirement aiohttp<1.1.0,>=1.0.0, but you'll have aiohttp 3.4.4 which is incompatible.
discord-py 0.16.12 has requirement websockets<4.0,>=3.1, but you'll have websockets 6.0 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: yarl, aiohttp
  Running setup.py install for yarl ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\laptop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Laptop\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rak2eq35\\yarl\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-fova16ok\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\yarl
    copying yarl\quoting.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\yarl
    copying yarl\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\yarl
    running egg_info
    writing yarl.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to yarl.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to yarl.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to yarl.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cache' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\_quoting.html'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\_quoting.*.so'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\_quoting.pyd'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'yarl\_quoting.*.pyd'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
    writing manifest file 'yarl.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying yarl\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win32-3.7\yarl
    copying yarl\_quoting.c -> build\lib.win32-3.7\yarl
    copying yarl\_quoting.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.7\yarl
    copying yarl\py.typed -> build\lib.win32-3.7\yarl
    running build_ext
    building 'yarl._quoting' extension

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\laptop\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Laptop\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rak2eq35\\yarl\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-fova16ok\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 3221225477 in C:\Users\Laptop\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rak2eq35\yarl\

C:\Users\Laptop>
```

I even downloaded aiohttp manually and tried to install this way (discord.py worked like that):

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.285]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

C:\Users\Laptop\Desktop\Python\discord\aiohttp-master>py setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing aiohttp.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to aiohttp.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to aiohttp.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to aiohttp.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'vendor'
warning: no files found matching 'aiohttp' anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'aiohttp\*.html'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
writing manifest file 'aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'aiohttp._websocket' extension

C:\Users\Laptop\Desktop\Python\discord\aiohttp-master>
```

However still nothing. I researched it on the internet and found nothing for my specific error.

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: `discord-py 0.16.12 has requirement aiohttp<1.1.0,>=1.0.0, but you'll have aiohttp 3.4.4 which is incompatible.`

This is the key for your problem.

Comment: So what am I supposed to do? Downloading an earlier version?

Comment: I think yes. Install requirements that satisfy `discord-py`.